# Python, FFMPEG: Redirecting output of FFMPEG subprocess call to a string

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I've managed to run an FFMPEG command using the subprocess module as shown below:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

This works fine, but it prints the verbose FFMPEG output to console. The program I'm writing is supposed to run for hundreds/thousands of files in a batch and I don't want detailed outputs for every file processed, unless the user chooses to do so. Can I redirect the console outputs and errors to strings, so that I can decide when I should and shouldn't print them?

This might be lame, but I tried the following snippet:

```
outputBuffer = BytesIO()
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stdout=outputBuffer)
```

But it gave me the following error:

```
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.
```

I saw other examples where the `POpen` interface was used, but given that I'm not communicating with the external command as it is running, and that I need to run this for a large number of items, I'd prefer something simpler, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

**Note:** I've found lots of questions in this broad topic, but I couldn't find anything perfectly relevant to my situation.

Comment: You can hide ffmpeg banner by adding `-hide_banner` flag and control output verbosity using `-loglevel` [flag](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Generic-options) to your command, for example `ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic [rest of your ffmpeg stuff]`.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem for me. :) I'm leaving the question open to see if there is a way to handle similar commands through Python.